Capturing in-memory OLTP transaction aborted errors in SQL Server
In one of my SQL Server 2016 Enterprise instances, sp_BlitzFirst is reporting hundreds of aborted transactions per second in one of my in-memory OLTP databases.
I've set up error logging with try/catch for all procedures in the DB but they've caught nothing yet. Similarly, an extended event set up to capture errors isn't showing anything related to aborted transactions.
The sys.dm_xtp_transaction_stats and sys.dm_os_performance_counters DMVs only seem to provide a total number of transactions aborted but don't provide details regarding the procedure(s) causing the errors.
It's probably an error related to the ones listed in this MS doc, but I have no way of knowing which one at the moment:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transactions-with-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15#conflict-detection-and-retry-logic
Is there any way to capture this type of error?

Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

I don't think so because I don't know where the error is occurring or what the specific error even is. All that is occurring is that running sp_blitzfirst will show a large number of aborted transactions for my in memory db.

Maybe the XE was set up incorrectly? Can you try this one? It always worked for me. Though maybe there is something different with in-memory database.

The one I was using was similar to yours. But I tried your one and still no relevant errors caught.

which exactly event you tried in Extended Events, to capture errors ? and can you post the code of XE event session. Normally, properly configured XE with error_reported event, should capture everything
